# Replacing strings in specific positions into a text and then rewriting all the text

Tags: python

I'm working on a text with several columns and many lines as given bellow;

I want to replace "A" in index[4] with "B".

```
ATOM 1 N ARG A  88   63.055   9.295   9.736  1.00 25.54           N 
ATOM 2 CA ARG A 88   61.952  10.108  10.353  1.00 26.02           C
```

and rewrite my text as:

```
ATOM 1 N ARG B  88   63.055   9.295   9.736  1.00 25.54           N
ATOM 2 CA ARG B 88   61.952  10.108  10.353  1.00 26.02           C
```

I'm using this script but it changes all "A" to "B".

```
file = open('1qib.pdb', 'r')
file2 = open('new.pdb', 'w')

for i, line in enumerate(file):
    s = line.split()[4]
    file2.write(line.replace(s, "B"))

file.close()
file2.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to do it like this:

```
file = open('1qib.pdb', 'r')
file2 = open('new.pdb', 'w')

for i, line in enumerate(file):
    spl = line.split() #1
    spl[4] = spl[4].replace("A", "B") #2
    newline = " ".join(spl) #3
    file2.write(newline) #4

file.close()
file2.close()
```

**Step-by-step explanation:**

1. Note that what you do here is to split the line first into list of string.

   ```
   spl = line.split()
   ```
2. Then you only want to replace the index=4 of the list of string to new item.

   ```
   spl[4] = spl[4].replace("A", "B")
   ```
3. And finally you rejoin the list

   ```
   newline = " ".join(spl)
   ```
4. before you write it to the file again

   ```
   file2.write(newline)
   ```

Comment: How can I apply the format bellow to construct the new text?                    "%-6s%5d %4s%1s%3s %1s%4d%1s   %8.3f%8.3f%8.3f%6.2f%6.2f          %2s%2s"

Comment: As I'm trying to keep the PDB file standard format.

Comment: @Berk I am sorry, I have never seen such format before... And I have never worked with PDB either, but you can look for the suitable tools in Google?

Answer (score 1):

`line.replace(src, dst)` means "take the string `line` and replace all instances of `src` with `dst`". So even if you define `src` as "whatever is found as the fifth word in `line`", the replace operation is applied to the entire line.

So don't do that - replace only that instance like this:

```
with open('1qib.pdb', 'r') as fin, open('new.pdb', 'w') as fout:
    for line in fin:
        items = line.split()
        items[4] = "B"
        fout.write(" ".join(items))
```